# Unity: how heavy is PlayerPrefs in unity in terms of memory and processing?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I have 2D game in which I am using around 200 different PlayerPrefs to store all types of data as strings and integers. I keep calling PlayerPrefs back and forth to set or get data. I want to know how good it is? Or I should switch to SQLite or Filing? our targeted devices are of 1GB ram max.
Data Example: Player1Name, Player1Score, Player1Enery, Player1Lives, Player1Hp, Player1Level1TimeTaken, Player1Level1Challenge1TimeTaken. And have we done it for dozens of players and several other preferences as well.
TIA

Comment: I think it depends how often you write/read data. It might cause some issues when you try to read e.g a lot of data in every frame. You can e.g create XML or JSON and store it as string variable. Than make operations on variable and read/write operation you can use e.g on start/ end game etc.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, I am not gonna save per frame but very often. Like on every event happening in game will process around 5 to 10 preferences. By saying event I mean New Game, Game end, Game win, Game lose etc

Comment: So, i think this will be OK. Maybe there is more efficient way and someone post that in answer, but in this situation your solution will be enough.

Comment: Affan, good news. 200 preferences is **absolutely nothing**.  You are worrying about **absolutely nothing**.

Comment: @PawełMarecki - what are you talking about buddy?  **Of course** Player Prefs takes care of that - it caches the info, and you need only write it when you specifically want to and know it is a good time to do so.  This is an absolute basic of using PlayerPrefs. (Note that as I mentioned below, you **can't use** PlayerPrefs, of course, in any project - it's one of the stupidest things in all of Unity (and that's saying something). You can't have totally un-obfiscated or un-encrypted prefs in a game.  For now 100% of developers use AntiCheat-ToolKit; eventually Unity will finally wake up ...

Comment: ... and realize they have to include game-ready (ie, encrypted, obfuscated) preferences "duh".

Comment: @AffanShahab, it's also common to just "automate" the keys of PlayerPrefs (that is to say, in AntiCheatToolKit).  You know?

Comment: @JoeBlow You're right of course. AntiCheat Toolkit is a must-have. I'm also using it in my projects. But in case of usage like get/set values it works similar to PlayerPrefs. It depends on programmer if he would like to buy AntiCheat or not. About cashing in PlayerPrefs i didn't know that and I'll try to remember that. It is never late to learn.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you for wonderful input. @JoeBlow no I didn't know about that. Can you please share further detail or some sample code. any link would be great too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading your comment, there will be no problem with `PlayerPrefs` by the way you using it. The only problem I see is that you are saving each player's data property individually.

> Data Example: Player1Name, Player1Score, Player1Enery, Player1Lives,
>   Player1Hp, Player1Level1TimeTaken, Player1Level1Challenge1TimeTaken.
>   And have we done it for dozens of players and several other
>   preferences as well. TIA

This is not the right way to save your data if you have many properties of a user. Assuming that's one or two variables, then you can, but you have more than 7 variables * number of players(dozens).

By the time you are done saving dozens of all those variables, there will be registry `keys` everywhere. You can verify this by going to `HKCU\Software[company name][product name] key` after saving your player dozen information.

Put those player information into a class then convert it Json and save it as one info data.

Player Data:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public string playerName;
    public int playerScore;
    public int playerEnergy;
    public int playerLives;
    public int playerHP;
    public float playerLevelTimeTaken;
    public float playerLevelChallengeTimeTaken;
}
```

**Save Player Info**:

```
void savePlayerInfo()
{
    //Create one for player one
    PlayerInfo playerInfo1 = new PlayerInfo();
    playerInfo1.playerName = "Affan 1";

    //Create one for player two
    PlayerInfo playerInfo2 = new PlayerInfo();
    playerInfo2.playerName = "Affan 2";

    //Create one for player three
    PlayerInfo playerInfo3 = new PlayerInfo();
    playerInfo3.playerName = "Affan 3";

    //Convert each of them to Json
    string p1Json = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerInfo1);
    string p2Json = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerInfo2);
    string p3Json = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerInfo3);

    //Now Save all 3 player Info
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("p1", p1Json);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("p2", p2Json);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("p3", p3Json);
}
```

**Load Player Info**:

```
void loadPlayerInfo()
{
    //Load all 3 player Info
    string p1Json = PlayerPrefs.GetString("p1");
    string p2Json = PlayerPrefs.GetString("p2");
    string p3Json = PlayerPrefs.GetString("p3");

    //Convert each of them back to class
    PlayerInfo playerInfo1 = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(p1Json);
    PlayerInfo playerInfo2 = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(p2Json);
    PlayerInfo playerInfo3 = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(p3Json);

    //Use
    Debug.Log("Player 1 Name: " + playerInfo1.playerName);
    Debug.Log("Player 2 Name: " + playerInfo2.playerName);
    Debug.Log("Player 3 Name: " + playerInfo3.playerName);
}
```

To make it more easier to iterate through them, make it an array then use `p0` to `p49` as the key. This assumes that you need player info for 50 players.

**To read**:

```
PlayerInfo[] players;
void loadPlayerArrayInfo()
{
    players = new PlayerInfo[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        players[i] = new PlayerInfo();
        string tempPlayerKey = "p" + i;
        string playerJson = PlayerPrefs.GetString(tempPlayerKey);
        players[i] = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(playerJson);
    }
}
```

This keeps your registry **clean** and makes it **easier** to move your player settings to another Game Engine if you are moving away from Unity.

Comment: Thank you very much @programmer. This seems to be a very good approach. Very easy and clean implementation example. I am accepting it as an answer.

Comment: Nice. Glad you find it useful.

Comment: Unfortunately you ... can't do this at all in the real world.  You simply can't use PlayerPrefs on any ordinary real-world game. 100% of real-world games have to use Anti-CheatToolKit.  @Programmer, I would love to see some encrypted way to do your outstanding example!

Comment: Well I looked at the question again and the question is about how heavy is `PlayerPrefs` not how secure it is.This answer is only to let him know that he shouldn't be saving each variable individually but instead merge each player info into one then save it. Json or xml are appropriate for this. Of-course, it is not secure at-all but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be used. Unity did not bother to secure it because it will take one bad man 20 minutes to reverse-engineer it and even post how it works online.

Comment: It's up to each programmer to protect the data before saving. There are many ways to protect each json string before saving. These includes md-5, md-6, and AES. Posting code for that will make this answer unnecessary longer. The rule is like this, if you are making a local game that saves data on a local machine, don't worry about secure saving. If this is an online game with multiple players then use encryption and `Anti-CheatToolKi` or develop your own variable tempering protection mechanism. Otherwise, you wasting your time. You shouldn't care what people do on their local machine.

Comment: This debate is quit useful for me. I learnt new things. would love to see simple some encryption techniques for such simple games.

Answer (score 0):

PlayerPrefs can read  and set 3 types of variables. Float, int and string. int and float are both 32 bytes in memory length. A string takes up 20+(n/2)*4 bytes where n is the number of characters in the string. The string size may vary depending on how the unity devs compile the c# code to native code. As you can see the sizes are pretty small even for devices with just 1 gb of ram. You can use these metrics to calculate the amount of ram your variables will take up but I would not worry about that. What you are experiencing right now is called premature optimization. Just code it in this way and see if it causes a problem  and then and only then optimize it.